# jquery validation based on drag & dropped items

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to learn about jquery as much as possible, looking at many examples around the web, but still got problem with events.

As you can see, I made a simple drag&drop thing using jquery UI, but all examples I found arround didn't help me with validating this.

I created correctAnswers but the problem is I have no idea how to validate them. As it's easy to see, 'a' goes to 1, 'b' goes to 2, and 'c' goes to 3, and when I click 'submit' button it validates.

```
var correctAnswers = ['a-1,b-2,c-3'];

$('.dragAble').draggable({
    containment: "#content",
    cursor: "move",
    snap: ".dropAble"
});
if (answers === correctAnswers) {
    $("#win").show();
} else {
    $("#fail").show();
};​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87tMj/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var correctAnswers = ['a-1', 'b-2', 'c-3'];
var results = [];

$('.dragAble').draggable({
    containment: "#content",
    cursor: "move",
    snap: ".dropAble",
});

$( ".dropAble" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        results.push($(ui.draggable).attr("id") + '-' + $(this).attr("id"));
    }
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
    console.log(results);
    result = true;
    $.each(results, function(index, value){
        if($.inArray(value, correctAnswers ) == -1){
            result = false;
        }

        if(!result) return;
    });

    if (result) {
        $("#win").show();
    } else {
        $("#fail").show();
    };
});​
```

Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aanred/x3jF3/. But this code has only basic function you need to improve it.