# Enabling/disabling drag and drop based on pre-defined action HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have used the guide provided on w3school to implement a drag and drop function in my website http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrop_html. Now what I wish to do is add a function of some sort that grants premission to user to use the drag and drop function.

Currntly anyone visiting my website can drag and drop elements but I want to add a feature, say for example, if user presses certain key on the keyboard or input certain word inside a specifc textfield.

Also, not sure if this is possible to have this, instead of having a textfield is it possible to allow the user to simply click on the webpage/document and type in a word that doesn't display on the screen but is being picked up by the website.

I have researched but haven't found anything useful to follow so any help is welcomed.

[jquery validation based on drag & dropped items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615567/jquery-validation-based-on-drag-dropped-items)

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?299067-Javascript-Drag-and-Drop-Function-with-validation%28Kindly-help-me-to-solve-this-prob%29

EDITED:

```
  var code = "";
    window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
        code = (code+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which)).substr(-11);
        if (code == "SECRET" ) {
            for(i = 0, i <=20, i++) {
            document.getElementById("dragID" + i).setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            alert('unlocked');
        }
}
    },false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your last question! 
Yes it's possible:

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236394/2543240

So now that we have picked up the entered code in a string, a simple `if` statement should do the job:

```
var code = "";
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
    code = (code+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which)).substr(-11);
    if (code == "SECRET" ) {
        $('#dragtarget').attr('draggable', "true");
        alert('unlocked');
    }
},false);
```

In your html code, set `draggable` attribute to `false`:

```
<p ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="false" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>
```

check this [***Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/fn4k4s35/)

**Edit:** Without using jQuery:

```
var code = "";
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
    code = (code+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which)).substr(-11);
    if (code == "SECRET" ) {
        document.getElementById("dragtarget").setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        alert('unlocked');
    }
},false);
```

***[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/fn4k4s35/1/)***

**Edit2:**

Add a button to activate dragging:

As you noted in your comment bellow.

Check this ***[Fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/fn4k4s35/2/)***

**Edit3:**

If you have multiple cases you can define a class, for example `class="targets"` for all of them.
Then iterate through multiple elements with same class:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("targets");

for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].setAttribute("draggable", "true");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer I haven't tried the code yet however, would I need to add a function for drag as well or does allowdrop picks that up?

Comment: Hi, just tried this code it does prevent the drop, however, even if you type in secret it won't let me drop

Comment: Nope, it still is not working I think its not picking up the text. I am trying in chrome.

Comment: @Henry check the Fiddle, it's disabled by default, just press s, e, c, r, e, t keys in order and after an alert saying `unlocked`! the element can be dragged.

Comment: Hi @webinan the first fiddle for some reason does not work for me but it works fine on the fiddle and the second fiddle works sometimes and only on 1 element. I understand this might be become I have different ids for each element but I tried looping through them but still no luck. Please see edit.

Comment: If possible can you also give me an example of where button is pressed to enable drag and drop?

Comment: Just copy and paste the line `document.getElement...` as much as you need and replace `dragtarget` with other ids. and I'll edit the answer for a button

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to use a for loop to loop through each id?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you considered using jQuery's draggable feature, but the API exposes a very simple mechanism for enabling/disabling drag-ability among other things.
Here's a code snippet

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
revert: true
});
$("#droppable").droppable();
```

And here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5xktf0g/

In this example, the validation is based on button click event, you could easily tie the validation to a key-up event and capture the key that was pressed. Append the key to a string and check the last "n" characters if they match your "n" character validation string.

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't mind using jquery but the only issue is will I need to change the way I written the drag and drop because I followed the guide on w3school.

Comment: Yes,it would require a change.Here's a good reason to consider changing it:jQuery's one main goal is to simplify complex operations done in javascript,for instance,the example on w3schools has about 15 lines of javascript to just enable drag/drop.With jQuery that gets done in 2 simple lines. It's very readable (for any future developers as well) and also exposes other API methods that make drag drop super cool.Have a look here: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/.Implementing any available feature would require lots of javascript lines of code.If any feature seems useful, i would suggest jQuery.